# How do I install pyperclip on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I use the command "pip install pyperclip" it gives me this error

```
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ts/tdt25dd52pg6ymt1tc1djd540000gn/T/pip-build-QWGKB1/pyperclip/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ts/tdt25dd52pg6ymt1tc1djd540000gn/T/pip-sfvxg3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ts/tdt25dd52pg6ymt1tc1djd540000gn/T/pip-build-QWGKB1/pyperclip/
```

Why is it that I do not have permission.

Comment: You are installing into the system packages, you will need to run as root `sudo pip install ...`. Alternatively, create a `virtualenv` and install in a virtual environment as a user.

Comment: Ahhh. @AChampion you are the best. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you get error `Permission denied` its because you are trying to access the root using normal commands. So trying running the command as root to get rid of `Permissin denied` error. Run `sudo command` i.e `sudo pip install pyperclip`

Answer (score 3):

Try it with

> sudo pip install pyperclip

Now if it throws some access deny error, try this:

> sudo pip -H install pyperclip

Answer (score 0):

//These below three commands worked for MacBook Pro to install Pip & Pyperclip

1./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip  install --upgrade pip

2./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/scripts

3.sudo pip3 install pyperclip

output: Downloading pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB) |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 3.7 MB/s Installing collected packages: pip Attempting uninstall: pip Found existing installation: pip 21.2.3 Uninstalling pip-21.2.3: Successfully uninstalled pip-21.2.3 Successfully installed pip-21.2.4

Collecting pyperclip Downloading pyperclip-1.8.2.tar.gz (20 kB) Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyperclip, since package 'wheel' is not installed. Installing collected packages: pyperclip Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... done Successfully installed pyperclip-1.8.2